# Is there a way to change the mortar geometry of the Brick Texture?

Tags: procedural

I started making procedural Cycles materials since a few days, and I find it very fun. After messing around with the nodes, I tried to create a brick texture. Here's my current progress :

[image: Brick Wall top view]

I wanted to know if there's a way to change the mortar geometry, to make it less "perfect", like on a real brick wall (for example [this one](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/62))

I already tried some things, like connecting Noise/Voronoi/Musgrave to the Vector input and the Mortar Size of the brick texture, but I didn't found anything that looked right...

Can someone help me ? Thanks !

---

*Sorry for the engrish, I'm French :x*

Comment: I can't tell you how to alter your nodes to come up with a procedural brick texture that is more like the image you linked to on Poliigon, what I can say, after looking at many in line images of masonry, and at many brick buildings in the real world, that the procedural you created and are wanting to modify, is much more representative of the work of a master brick mason than the image on Poliigon.  I don't know why you want to modify the image, but it does not look like the work of a master mason.

Comment: "*Connecting Noise/Voronoi/Musgrave to the Vector input*" sounds like the right solution, it is what I generally use myself. What about it displeases you?

Comment: @brasshat I want to do this because I'd like to do some really old bricks, like on this image texture.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos well, it just does strange things... For example, pluging a Voronoi into the Vector Input just shows some circles.

Comment: Well you can just plug it in brute force, you need some softening of the effect. Try a color mix node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

[image: distort bricks]

The Noise texture is used to distort the Vector input to the Brick Texture node - this results in distortion of the brick texture. Note how the Factor of the Add node (a MixRGB node set to 'Add') is extremely low and the Scale of the Noise texture increased to 75 to produce many small ripples in the lines of mortar.

Comment: It's awesome ! Thanks !
Is there a way to do this without UV unwrapping the mesh ? :)

Comment: Sure - jist replace the UV Map node with a Texture Coordinate node and use either the Generated or Object coordinate.

Comment: Is there also a way to get noisy brick width? If you look at brick walls they have normally not this uniform brick size. Even the rows or mortars are different.

Comment: @Lutz This is an old question and the making bricks with varying bricks could be quite complicated (the above solution was a simple distortion - I don't think that will work for the bricks since you'd want the edges to still be straight). I think you'd be better starting a new question including a full description and screenshots of the results you're after.